# C# [regex] trim spaces before specific word

Tags: c#, regex

I want to trim all spaces between numbers before words "usd" and "eur".
I have regex pattern like this:

```
@"\b(\d\s*)+\s(usd|eur)"
```

How to exclude space and usd|eur from result match?.

String example: `"sdklfjsd 10   343 usd ds 232 300 eur"`

Result should be: `"sdklfjsd 10343 usd ds 232300 eur"`

```
string line = "2 300 $ 12 Asdsfd 2  300  530 usd and 2  351 eur";
        MatchCollection matches;
        Regex defaultRegex = new Regex(@"\b(\d+\s*)+(usd|eur)");        
        matches = defaultRegex.Matches(line);
        WriteLine("Parsing '{0}'", line);
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < matches.Count; ctr++)
            WriteLine("={0}){1}", ctr, matches[ctr].Value);
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. I'd take a look at using Regex.Replace, assuming you have a correct regex pattern for your purposes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Can there be `"txt 10   456  343 usd ds 2 232 300 eur"`?

Comment: I've added what I have, result would be fine without space and usd|eur

Comment: Sorry, do you mean to extract these numbers? If yes, try `Regex.Matches(line, @"(?i)\d[\d\s]*?(?=\s*(?:usd|eur))").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Replace(" ", "")).ToList()`. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OOY1hV/2).

Comment: So, all you wanted is `Regex.Replace(line, @"(?<=\d)\s+(?=[\d\s]*\s(?:usd|eur))", "")`, right? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OOY1hV/1). The accepted solution looks too cumbersome if you need just that,

Comment: I need to use MatchEvaluator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There my be a more eloquent way, but it can be done easily with a [`MatchEvaluator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator)

```
new Regex(@"\b(\d+\s*)+(?=\s(usd|eur))").
    Replace("sdklfjsd 10   343  usd ds 232 300 eur",
        m => string.Join("", m.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value.Trim())))
```

The Regex `\b(\d+\s*)+(?=\s(usd|eur))` uses a look-ahead to only match numbers that are followed by `\s(usd|eur)` and a grouping to match each consecutive match to `\d+\s*` (I assume the `\b` boundary from your question so that with `abc12 34 56 eur` it would only match `34 56` is desired, remove it otherwise).

Then for each match it gets all of that group's captures, trims them all, and concatenates them together to produce the replacement text.

(Note that generally currency codes should be capitalised, so you my have another issue there).

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `(\d+) *(\d+)(?= (?:usd|eur))`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wp1Cd7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there only two numbers, you can use

`\b(\d+)\s*(\d+)(?=\s(usd|eur))` with a replacement string of `$1$2`

Comment: @l'L'l he said it has to be followed by eur or usd.

Comment: @l'L'l what about the string `abc 123 123 zzz`. With your solution, it would turn it into abc 123123 zzz`, which isn't correct according to the question.

Comment: it should ignore other numbers without usd and eur

Comment: Why do you use a word boundary though? and there's really no point to a lookahead either... `(\d+)\s*(\d+\s(usd|eur))` would do it in 20 less steps.

Comment: @l'L'l if you don't use a lookahead, then you would have to do $1$2 $3. Which is what I had originally, but I thought this was cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a posotive lookbehind and a positive lookahead to match all the spaces you want to remove:

`(?<=\d)\s+(?=(?:\d+\s+)*\d+\s+(?:eur|usd)\b)`

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\d)` Positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left is
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace characters
- `(?=` Positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is

  - `(?:\d+\s+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching 1+ digits followed by 1+ whitespace characters
  - `\d+\s+(?:eur|usd)\b` match 1+ digits followed by 1+ whitespace characters and eur or usd
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cd%29%5cs%2b%28%3f%3d%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5cs%2b%29*%5cd%2b%5cs%2b%28%3f%3aeur%7cusd%29%5cb%29&i=sdklfjsd+10+++343+usd+ds+232+300+eur%0d%0a%0d%0asdklfjsd+10+++343+usd+ds+232+300+eur++++test%0d%0a2+300+%24+12+Asdsfd+2++300++530+usd+and+2++351+eur)

```
string line = "2 300 $ 12 Asdsfd 2  300  530 usd and 2  351 eur";
string result = Regex.Replace(line , @"(?<=\d)\s+(?=(?:\d+\s+)*\d+\s+(?:eur|usd)\b)", "");
Console.WriteLine(result); // 2 300 $ 12 Asdsfd 2300530 usd and 2351 eur
```

[Demo C#](https://ideone.com/DYZtaj)